# Issue deploying Nuxt static site to Netlify

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, netlify

I'm having issues deploying my static Nuxt site (version 2.15.8) to Netlify. When I push to my git branch that then generates a build, but the builds are failing with the following error:

```
    ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
11:33:46 AM:   1. Build command from Netlify app                             
11:33:46 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
11:33:46 AM: ​
11:33:46 AM: $ npm run generate
11:33:46 AM: > mydomain.co.uk@1.0.0 generate
11:33:46 AM: > nuxt generate
11:33:56 AM: node: ../src/coroutine.cc:134: void* find_thread_id_key(void*): Assertion `thread_id_key != 0x7777' failed.
Aborted
11:33:56 AM: ​
11:33:56 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
11:33:56 AM:   "build.command" failed                                        
11:33:56 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
11:33:56 AM: ​
11:33:56 AM:   Error message
11:33:56 AM:   Command failed with exit code 134: npm run generate
11:33:56 AM: ​
11:33:56 AM:   Error location
11:33:56 AM:   In Build command from Netlify app:
11:33:56 AM:   npm run generate
11:33:56 AM: ​
11:33:56 AM:   Resolved config
11:33:56 AM:   build:
11:33:56 AM:     command: npm run generate
11:33:56 AM:     commandOrigin: ui
11:33:56 AM:     publish: /opt/build/repo/dist
11:33:56 AM:     publishOrigin: ui
11:33:56 AM: Caching artifacts
11:33:56 AM: Started saving node modules
11:33:56 AM: Finished saving node modules
11:33:56 AM: Started saving build plugins
11:33:56 AM: Finished saving build plugins
11:33:56 AM: Started saving yarn cache
11:34:00 AM: Finished saving yarn cache
11:34:00 AM: Started saving pip cache
11:34:00 AM: Finished saving pip cache
11:34:00 AM: Started saving emacs cask dependencies
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this may be?

Comment: Does it work locally?

Comment: @kissu it did thanks. I found the issue, Node 16 was being used in Netlify but that's not supported. I therefore added a NODE_VERSION variable in my netlify.toml config file and set that to 15.14.0. That solved the issue

Comment: Maybe prefer using the LTS aka v14.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was the Node.js version used by the project.
Netlify does not support Node v16, setting the version manually in a `netlify.toml` file to v15.14.0 solved the issue!